# from list to string with formatting

Tags: vb.net

i have a function getSelectedNumbers that take as input 3 list of number. after a manipulation i need to obtain a string in the format

"[1_3,10,20,30,500],[1_1,2],[]"

if the list is empty i need to have in the string the "[]" char

i wrote the below function but i need to manage the empty case.

Based on comment of Anu6is : 
i was able to rewrite my code as below

'''vb

```
Public Function getSelectedNumbers() As String          
        Dim selectedNumbers1 As IList(Of Element) =  repo.CanvasTerminalProduct.BoardDetails.Panel.pnlSuper3Panel1.Find(".//div[@class='selected']")
        Dim selectedNumbers2 As IList(Of Element) =  repo.CanvasTerminalProduct.BoardDetails.Panel.pnlSuper3Panel2.Find(".//div[@class='selected']")
        Dim selectedNumbers3 As IList(Of Element) =  repo.CanvasTerminalProduct.BoardDetails.Panel.pnlSuper3Panel3.Find(".//div[@class='selected']")
        Dim list1 As New List(Of String)
        Dim list2 As New List(Of String)
        Dim list3 As New List(Of String)

        For i As Integer = 0 To selectedNumbers1.Count -1
            list1.Add(selectedNumbers1(i).GetAttributeValue("innerText").ToString)
        Next i
        For i As Integer = 0 To selectedNumbers2.Count -1
            list2.Add(selectedNumbers2(i).GetAttributeValue("innerText").ToString)
        Next i
        For i As Integer = 0 To selectedNumbers3.Count -1
            list3.Add(selectedNumbers3(i).GetAttributeValue("innerText").ToString)
        Next i

        'Create List of List
        Dim selectedNumbersList As New List(Of List(Of String)) From {list1, list2, list3}

        Dim builder As New StringBuilder 'Used to build the output
        'Convert all the list in the correct string format using the join 
        For Each listX As List(Of String) In selectedNumbersList
            builder.Append("[1_").Append(String.Join(",", listX)).Append("],") 'String.Join() give you a comma delmited string
        Next
        'Remove the last, and the [1_] that are not needed
        Dim strSelectedNunmber As String = builder.ToString().TrimEnd(","c)         
        strSelectedNunmber = strSelectedNunmber.ToString().Replace("[1_]","[]")

        Return str
    End Function
```

'''

now my question is there is a better way to generate the list1 list2 list3 ?

Comment: I don't understand why you complicate it so much when it can be done in a simple loop.

Comment: One Loop ? how you can mange the different size of the List ?

Comment: I posted an answer, you edit the question also, so before doing the loop you call .Sort on list so you get ascending values.

Comment: What exactly is `Element` is it always just an `Integer`?

Comment: element are n Div object that had innerText property

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is assuming that Element is simply an Integer

```vb
Public Function getSelectedNumbers() As String
    Dim selectedNumbers1 As New List(Of Integer) From {20, 30, 500, 10, 3}  'Unordered list
    Dim selectedNumbers2 As New List(Of Integer) From {1, 2, 500}           'Ordered list
    Dim selectedNumbers3 As New List(Of Integer)                            'empty list

    Dim selectedNumbersList As New List(Of List(Of Integer)) From {selectedNumbers1, selectedNumbers2, selectedNumbers3}
    Dim builder As New StringBuilder 'Used to build the output

    For Each list In selectedNumbersList
        list.Sort() 'Sort your list
        builder.Append("[").Append(String.Join(",", list)).Append("],") 'String.Join() give you a comma delmited string
    Next

    Return builder.ToString.TrimEnd(","c) 'Remove the final comma (,) and return the formatted string
End Function
```

`[3,10,20,30,500],[1,2,500],[]`

Comment: Thank you it was i needed but i need to make a chage because the correct output format was "[1_3,10,20,30,500],[1_1,2,500],[]"

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you?

```
    Dim selectedNumbers1 As New List(Of Integer) From {20, 30, 500, 10, 3}
    Dim selectedNumbers2 As New List(Of Integer) From {1, 2, 500}
    Dim selectedNumbers3 As New List(Of Integer)

    'either make 3 loops or 1, but you have to make a list of lists first
    Dim selectedNumbersList As New List(Of List(Of Integer)) From {selectedNumbers1, selectedNumbers2, selectedNumbers3}

    For Each listX In selectedNumbersList
        listX.Sort()
        Dim ReturnString As String = "["
        If listX.Count > 0 Then
            For Each itemvalue In listX
                ReturnString &= itemvalue & ","
            Next
            ReturnString = ReturnString.Remove(ReturnString.Length - 1)
        End If
        ReturnString &= "]"
        Debug.Print(ReturnString)
    Next

'[3,10,20,30,500]
'[1,2,500]
'[]
```